# using jedit the split pane resizes proportionally on one system and not on another

Tags: resize, window, jedit

I am using JEdit on two Ubuntu systems (12.4, 10.4) and having an issue with vertically-split window.

When I resize the whole JEdit window, two side-by-side split panes resize proportionally on one system (10.4) but on the other system the left pane stays a fixed size and all changes to overall window width get applied to only the right pane.

Both are JEdit v 4.4.2, both have only plugins: jdiff and buffertabs.

Is there a setting to turn weighting or proportional resize on?

Thanks!

UPDATE: This appears to be related to the JDiff plugin. The proportional resize stops working after you turn jdiff 'dual diff' on and then off. JDiff causes the panels to be set to equal sizes; when you turn off dual diff, the original proportions are restored but proportional resize is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed seems to be a bug in the JDiff plugin that changes some property of the SplitPane and doesn't restore it if there were splits before already. Maybe it shouldn't change that property after all, but use the same setting for proportional resizes. You should report this to the Plugin Bugs Tracker: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=browse&group_id=588&atid=565475
As a work-around you can just unsplit and resplit the window, then the SplitPane is setup correctly again.

Comment: Wow, that's a new personal best in getting an answer - almost 6 months since I asked! :-) Thanks much for your answer. The problem appears to be solved in the current version of JDiff so I did not submit to tracker.

Comment: Yeah, I just have seen there is a jEdit question without answer and I thought I'd drop a note. :-)
I don't look for questions on SO too regularly. *g*

Hm, really? I tested with latest version 3.3.0 of JDiff and it still happens for me like you described.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.4 / Unity. JEdit 4.0.0 in 'server' mode. Plugin mgr shows jdiff 3.3.0. I don't have the problem in that config - JEdit in JDiff dual diff resizes both vertical windows in matching sizes. Are you using the same versions as I am?

Comment: I see the same behaviour in Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity and Windows 7 each with jEdit 5.0.0 and JDiff 3.3.0. If I first split the window horizontally, then start a dual diff and then end the dual diff, which is supposed to restore the splitting state before the dual diff, then I have the behaviour you originally described. Before, while having split manually and during the diff, the resizing is symmetric, but after quitting the diff, I have the unsymmetric resize until I unsplit and resplit in jEdit.

Comment: Yes, forgot the issue occurred _after_ turning off dual diff. Submitted to sourceforge as bug # 3613877 (thanks for suggesting where to submit :-)